# Best network tuning variables for a Linux proxy

Tags: linux, web-server, proxy, tcp, tuning

What are the best settings to tune so that Linux can handle a very large amount of TCP connections such as would be seen by a proxy server or a webserver?

I'm using Centos6 and squid and am seeing a large amount of TIME_WAIT connections backing up until finally the machine stops responding. The machine isn't loaded at the time, and is having trouble making ingoing and outgoing connections.

I've had several suggestions of tuning `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse` but they mention bad interactions with load balancers and NAT both of which are used in my situation.

Comment: Which connections / end points are causing the problems? Have you looked to check if FIN/RST packets are getting lost somewhere?

Comment: The issue seems to be between our load balancer and the proxy hosts. I have confirmed that no packets are going missing between the two using wireshark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to tune down this one:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
```

Something like

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 600
```

should be a lot better for your situation.

Also, make sure you have tuned the local port range. By default in most distros it's

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    61000
```

Something like

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1025    65534
```

should work lot better.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try reducing the /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout. If you're using keepalive you may want to fiddle with /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl and /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes ?